# After completing a stage, how this activity will come in initial stage, just like fresh activity

Tags: android

i am creating an Alphabets app, in this app there are 26 textviewand below a Button in which random images ,i have to set matching characters, every this is running perfect, but
after completing a cycle, some times, its media file/audio file doesn't work properly
what i do , please help me 
i just want after completing 26 characters, activity works like initial stage, like a fresh game, fresh Activity

Answer (score 0):

i guess you should place an intent to your mainactivity in the function/activity where you can verify your condition:

```
  if(verify your condition){
 Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

 context.startActivity(startIntent);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate your activity after your condition matches.. call this function of activity.

```
this.recreate();
```

this will refresh all states of your current activity.